# Scrolling Div content javascript and ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I've looked at all the div scrolling stuff here but none of it seems to work, i'm just trying to get a page with rails content loaded into a chat frame and have that div scroll to the bottom like a normal chat window would. everything loads fine, theres just no scrolling.

html file:

```
<html>
<head>  
<title>Chat - Customer Module</title>  
</head>  
<div id="wrapper">  
<div id="menu">  
    <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b></b></p>  
    <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>  
    <div style="clear:both"></div>  
</div>  
<div id="chatbox">
    <% @array.each do |i| %>
    <dt><%=Time.parse(i["createdAt"]).to_time  %></dt>
    <h3><dd><%= i["text"]  %></dd></h3>
    <br />
    <% end %>

</div>  

<form name="message" action="">  
    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />  
    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />  
</form>  
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
// jQuery Document  
$(document).ready(function(){  
console.log("loading")
var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height before the request  
var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height after the request  
        if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){  
            $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal');  
            }  
});  
</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {  
font:12px arial;  
color: #222;  
text-align:center;  
padding:35px; }  
form, p, span {  
margin:0;  
padding:0; }  
input { font:12px arial; }  
a {  
color:#0000FF;  
text-decoration:none; }  
a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }  
#wrapper, #loginform {  
margin:0 auto;  
padding-bottom:25px;  
background:#EBF4FB;  
width:504px;  
border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }  
#loginform { padding-top:18px; }  
#loginform p { margin: 5px; }  
#chatbox {  
text-align:left;  
margin:0 auto;  
margin-bottom:25px;  
padding:10px;  
background:#fff;  
height:350px;  
width:430px;  
border:1px solid #ACD8F0;  
overflow:auto; }  
#usermsg {  
width:395px;  
border:1px solid #ACD8F0; }  
#submit { width: 60px; }  
.error { color: #ff0000; }  
#menu { padding:12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px; }  
.welcome { float:left; }  
.logout { float:rightright; }  
.msgln { margin:0 0 2px 0; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code after the request:

height = $('#checkbox').offset().top;

$("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: height+ $('#checkbox').height()}, 'normal');